# How can I convert Field from Reflection to its actual type?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my code:

```
   using System.Reflection;
    
    
    namespace WinFormsApp1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var i=this.GetType().GetField("LetterA",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);         
            }
        List<string> LetterA = new List<string>();
        List<string> LetterB = new List<string>();
        List<string> LetterC = new List<string>();
        ///and so on List<string>
    }
}
```

There are so many lists in the class and I want to get it by Reflection and add value to the list.

As you see, in my code:

```
this.GetType().GetField("LetterA",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance)
```

I can get the filed now. However, I cannot convert to its actual type(`List<string>`) for it will reports error when I do it like this:

```
var i=this.GetType().GetField("LetterA",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance) as List<string>;
```

How can I convert to its actual type? Thank you.

Comment: **Which** error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that `i` only represents a field, you still need to call [`GetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue?view=net-7.0) to proceed.

```
var j = (List<string>)i.GetValue(this);
```